# Android facebook sdk 4.2.0 issue with sharing gif via custom interface

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

Sharing gif via Share Dialog is working fine and Facebook show a Gif Preview, But sharing via Custom Interface using ShareApi.share(), It makes the Link preview not the Gif Preview. Is there any extra setting while sharing via Custom Interface, which is not mentioned in Facebook's SDK Docs. Below are my both code samples:

1. Share Via ShareDialog(It displays the Gif Preview)

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(shareUrl)) // .gif link
                .build();
ShareDialog.show(getActivity(), content);
```

2. Share Via Custom Inteface(It does not display the Gif Preview, rather it shows the link preview)

```
ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(shareUrl)) // .gif link
                .build();
ShareApi.share(content, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Share Successful");                 
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
        Log.e(TAG, "Share Cancelled");                  
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
        if (e != null) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Share Error: " + e.toString());
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Share Error");
        }                   
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi, Can you share the tutorial for Facebook sharing examples?

Comment: Hi, Here is the link to documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android